# How can I export my websites data to an .xlsx file?

Tags: xml, export-to-excel

I am displaying a table on my website and want to provide users the option to download it. So far, I've been wrapping it in an HTML file with an .xls extension. When downloaded, this opens in excel and displays the correct data.

Of late, users have been complaining that when they open the file, they get a "The file format and extension of filename.xls don't match..." error. Turns out that Microsoft had released a security patch that would show this warning.

My question is, what kind of file should I write my data into so that the warnings don't come up?

I would like to write the file myself instead of using PHP or any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Excel can open [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I should have specified, I need formatting options too

Comment: So let the users download it in HTML format. Why does it have to be Excel? If you're writing HTML, let them save the HTML file you produce as-is. If you need it in Excel format, you have to write it in Excel format. Simply changing the file extension from .html to .xls never should have worked, because .html is not a binary .xls file.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your response. I inherited this legacy code that wrote to HTML. I'd like to write straight to an excel file if possible. But the only resource I could find for that was SpreadsheetML. Is that what you meant by Excel format?

Comment: @rahs [Welcome to PhpSpreadsheet's documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) shows SpreadsheetML as applying to Excel 2003. You would probably want [Office Open XML.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).

Comment: Rahs: What @Andrew said. :-)